# Function similar to document.ready() in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

Is there something like `document.ready()` in `Puppeteer`?

There is:

```
page.waitForSelector(selector)
```

Since there are so many same-name selector on any HTML page, how can this function can be sure that the right page has been loaded? It is a simple function, but caused quite a few errors when I use it before `page.content()`. I'm not sure what is missed about this function.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`page.waitForNavigation()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) as an alternative to jQuery's [`document.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function:

```
await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'});             // consider navigation to be finished when the load event is fired.
await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'}); // consider navigation to be finished when the DOMContentLoaded event is fired.
await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});     // consider navigation to be finished when there are no more than 0 network connections for at least 500 ms.
await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});     // consider navigation to be finished when there are no more than 2 network connections for at least 500 ms.
```

Alternatively, you can use the `waitUntil` option in [`page.goto()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) to wait for the document to load:

```
await page.goto('https://example.com/', {waitUntil: 'load'});
await page.goto('https://example.com/', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
await page.goto('https://example.com/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
await page.goto('https://example.com/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
```

Comment: The `page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'})` caused error 30 second after it has been executed .  Very strange!  `(node:12768) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
    at Promise.then (C:\d\code\js\wbot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:1230:21)
    at <anonymous>`

Comment: @user938363 You can increase the timeout limit using `page.waitForNavigation({timeout: 60000, waitUntil: 'load'})` or [`page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(60000)`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetdefaultnavigationtimeouttimeout).

Comment: Hi `Grant Miller`, the strange thing is that the line of the `page.waitForNavigation` has been executed and it is executing in a  following `do loop`  when the error pops up. In the `do loop`, there is a line of `page.reload({waitUntil: 'load'})`. But the error pointing to the line of `page.waitForNavigation`. Could be the problem is actually about `page.reload`?

Comment: Use waitForFunction instead,  `await page.waitForFunction(() => document.readyState === "complete");`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes waitForNavigation just timeout. I came up with other solution using the waitForFunction, checking if document is in ready state.

```
await page.waitForFunction(() => document.readyState === "complete");
```